# Checkbox not filtering as expected with jquery and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I've been struggling with some jquery and php. I have some data I receive from, one of the input from php is put in a class like this:

```
<span class="<?php echo $row1['Tag']; ?>">
```

I can see the class is add'ed to the DOM as excepted.

I want to use the class in a checkbox filter function with jquery and jquerymobile.

This is were I get the checkbox input:

```
  <div data-role="panel" id="mypanel" data-position="left" data-display="push" data-theme="a">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Menu</h1>
        </div>  


    <form>
        <fieldset data-role="collapsible">
            <legend>Søg</legend>
                <div class="tags">
                <label for="textinput-f">Vælg Virksomheder:</label>

                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1-a" id="it" rel="it">
                <label for="it">It</label>

                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-2-a" id="maskin" rel="maskin">
                <label for="maskin">Maskin</label>

                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-3-a" id="design" rel="design">
                <label for="design">Design</label>

                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-4-a" id="elektro" rel="elektro">
                <label for="elektro">Elektro</label>
                </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

My html were I input the php looks like this:

```
<div data-role="content" id="cont">
           <h1>h</h1>

<form>
    <input data-type="search" id="divOfPs-input">
</form>
<div  class="elements" data-filter="true" data-input="#divOfPs-input" data-role="collapsibleset" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a">

<?php       
         mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
        @mysql_select_db($database) or die("<b>Unable to specified database</b>");
        //MySQL Query to read data

        $result1 = mysql_query("select * from Company");

        while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
?>
         <div class="results" data-mini="true" data-role="collapsible">
             <h3 ><?php echo $row1['CompanyName']; ?></h3>
              <p class="doh">

                <?php echo '<img style="max-width:100%" src="data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($row1['CompanyLogo']) . '" />';?></br>
                <span>Fagområde:</span> <?php echo $row1['CompanyField']; ?></br>
                <span>Telefon:</span> <?php echo $row1['ContactPhone']; ?></br>
                <span>Email:</span> <?php echo $row1['ContactEmail']; ?></br>
                <?php echo '<img style="max-width:100%" src="data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($row1['ContactImage']) . '" />';?></br>
                <span>Beskrivelse:</span> <?php echo $row1['CompanyDetail']; ?> </br>
                <span class="<?php echo $row1['Tag']; ?>">Søger:</span> <?php echo $row1['Tag']; ?>
              <p>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>

</div>      

<?php
        mysql_close(); // Closing Connection with Server
?>
</div>
```

and my jquery look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.results').show();


        $('div.tags').find('input:checkbox').on('click', function () {

            $('.results').hide();

            $('div.tags').find('input:checked').each(function () {

                $('.doh > span.' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();
            });

        });

   });
```

I can hide my content with the  `$('.results').hide();` but it doesn't filter and show my content afterward as I try to with:

```
        $('div.tags').find('input:checked').each(function () {
            $('.doh > span.' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();
        });
```

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: Wow, can you clean up your post please. I d'ont even understand what are you trying to achieve and what is your problem. I can give you a clue, based and your code, just do that : `$('div.tags').find('input:checked').each(function () { console.log($(this));...` You may have a surprise or your answer. I think that `$(this)` in this case isn't what your expect it to be ;)

Comment: Sorry for the mess. Will try to clean my question a bit. I put code you gave to console-log, but I'm not sure what the point is?

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is the same as this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nanoquantumtech/Ddnuh/)

Comment: haa, much better with the fiddle. The only thing I can see is to check wether your dynamic spans have the corresponding class. For instance, `php echo $row1['Tag'];` must be either elektro, or maskin or design...

Comment: When I check the DOM in Chrome I can see this:
`<span class="elektro">Søger:</span>`
Which tell me the class is add'ed. I just don't understand why it isn't selected in the jquery script?

Comment: if you do that `$('div.tags').find('input:checked').each(function () { console.log("a box is checked");`, do you see something printed in the console ? also, I suggest to attach your handler directly to document and not to the `div.tags`, but if your are sure, `div.tags` do exists when document is ready. => `$(document).on("click",".tags", function(){...}`

Comment: I get "a box is checked" in console. Good hint to check for that! The rest you suggest I'm not sure if I understand?

Comment: Do you mean like this:
`$(document).ready(function () { $('.results').show(); $(document).find('input:checkbox').on('click', function () {
                $('.results').hide();
                 
                $(document).find('input:checked').each(function () { 
                    $('.doh > span.' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();
                });
             
            });
          
       });`
?

Comment: I tried it in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nanoquantumtech/Ddnuh/) but it doesn't seem to work, if I did what you explained right?

Comment: ar, no `$(document).ready(function () { $('.results').show(); $(document).on("click",".tags", function(){ $('div.tags').find('input:checked').each(function () {...}} `

Comment: Like this:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tommyotzen/t387kz67/1/)
? It doesn't work not in fiddle neither on my server?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62749/discussion-between-tchdvlp-and-tommy-otzen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution, based on our discussion on the chat
http://jsfiddle.net/TCHdevlp/t387kz67/14/

For future readers, there were two chunks
1st : use `closest` to go up the dom to find a container
2nd : don't use click event but "change" event on checkboxes